# How to test and deploy a Docker production image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm developing on Ruby on Rails and start using Docker for deployment for a month.

The following are the steps I'm working on.

> 1. dev on my laptop
> 2. push to gitlab
> 3. build a single image including test and production gems
> 4. run rspec against this image
> 5. (pass)push to registry, (fail) discard image

With this workflow, I will have a single image that have all testing, development and production gems.

The workflow that I find from talking with many people

> 1. dev on my lap top
> 2. push to gitlab
> 3. build test image (all gems necessary for testing)
> 4. run rspec against test image
> 5. (pass)build another image for deployment without test gems and push to docker registry, (fail)discard the image

With this method, I think it's violating the purpose of Docker (the image that being test should be indifference from the one that will be deploy).

How to specify and implement an approach that test and push a production image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Testing Strategies for Docker Containers](https://hackernoon.com/testing-strategies-for-docker-containers-f633e261e75a)" by [Alexei Ledenev](https://twitter.com/alexeiled), your first approach has significant drawbacks:

> - Increases the image size - because it contains testing tools, required packages, test scripts, and perhaps even test data
> - Pollutes image runtime environment with test specific configuration and may even introduce an unneeded dependency (required by integration testing)
> - We also need to decide what to do with the test results and logs; how and where to export them

A different approach (closer to the second one you mention) is making a  “Test Aware Container”:

> We believe Docker should make `docker-test` part of the container management lifecycle.
>
> As mentioned before, Docker has a very useful **[`ONBUILD` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/onbuild)**. This instruction allows us to trigger another build instruction on succeeding builds.
>   The basic idea is to use `ONBUILD` instruction when running `docker-test` command.
>
> The flow executed by `docker-test` command:
>
> `docker-test` will search for `ONBUILD` instructions in application Dockerfile and will …
>
> - generate a temporary `Dockerfile.test` from original `Dockerfile`
> - execute `docker build -f Dockerfile.test [OPTIONS] PATH` with additional options supported by docker build command: `-test` that will be automatically appended to `tag` option
> - If build is successful, execute `docker run -v ./tests/results:/var/tests/results [OPTIONS] IMAGE:TAG-test [COMMAND] [ARG...]`
> - Remove `Dockerfile.test` file

(the article goes on describing an Integration Test Container)